# Retrieving GWAS information with R

Tags: r, genetics

I am trying to get specific disease-related information from the [GWAS catalog](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/gwas/). This can be done directly from the website via a spreadsheet download. But I was wondering if I could possibly do it programmatically in R. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Avoks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the function download.file() and the package rcurl (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html) - this should do what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks Rainer, I will check them out.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download *.tsv* file(s) first and manually edit them.
   This is because GWAS Catalog files contain HTML symbols, like ***&#x000A7*** in "Behçet's disease" (defining that special fourth letter). The ***#*** in these symbols will be interpreted by R as an end of line, thus you will get an error message, e.g.:

```
line 2028 did not have 34 elements
```

So you downlad it first, open in plain text editor, automatically replace every ***#*** with empty character, and only then load it into R with:

```
read.table("gwas_catalog_v1.0-associations_e91_r2018-02-21.tsv",sep="\t",h=T,stringsAsFactors = F,quote="")
```